# List Index Out of Range When Printing List (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've been writing some code that basically prints a dictionary, but with the keys in alphabetical order. So I start with any dictionary like this one...

```
d = {'a' : 52, 'b' : 30, 'c' : 36}
```

so I made this function to convert and display them...

```
def alph_order(d):
    l = sorted(d.keys())
    for i in range(0, len(l), 2):
        l.insert(i+1, d[l[i]])
    l.append(d[l[-1]])
    for i in range(0, len(l), 2):
        print(l[i], '     :', l[i+1])
```

so it prints out...

```
a     : 52
b     : 30
c     : 36
```

But when I add another key and value to the dictionary and call the function again, it prints out the first three in alphabetical order, and then says...

```
    print(l[i], '     :', l[i+1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It works when I start the dictionary with three keys, but every time I add one, the last one isn't displayed. Why is this happening? I figured that since the list now has two more objects in them, it should still work, but it doesn't.

Comment: What's your new list looks like?

Comment: Given the way your loop looks, that error can only occur if your list is of odd (not even) length.  So you must not be adding two new members, but just one.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug with the code you have converting the `dict` to a `list`?

Comment: `l = sorted(d.keys())
for i in range(0, len(l), 2):
        l.insert(i+1, d[l[i]])
l.append(d[l[-1]])`

Comment: thats the code I'm using to convert the dictionary to the ordered list. d is the dictionary and l is the list. the list looks like it should before entering the code in the original post, with an even number of objects

Comment: Can you post the code in the original post so it is formatted properly?

Comment: the post has been revised

Comment: Your code is a mess and is very C-style. Try to forget your code completely and write it more Pythonic by reading others' posts.

Comment: Forgive my code-writing. I'm have like a month of experience and I'm just using what I've learned in class

Comment: You can accomplish this with ``print('\n'.join('{}    : {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in sorted(d.items())))``.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid your problem with this way:

```
>>> for k, v in zip(l[::2], l[1::2]):
...     print(k, '     :', v)
... 
('a', '     :', 52)
('b', '     :', 30)
('c', '     :', 36)
```

Anyway, here is more elegant and just right way to do that you want:

```
>>> d = {'a': 52, 'b': 30, 'c': 36}
>>> for item in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
...    print(item)
... 
('a', 52)
('b', 30)
('c', 36)
```

Answer (score -1):

You currently must have an error in the code being used to convert your dictionary to your required list format.

Here is your code:

```
l = sorted(d.keys())
for i in range(0, len(l), 2): 
    l.insert(i+1, d[l[i]]) 

l.append(d[l[-1]])
```

This **does not** insert all of the values from your dictionary into the list.  If your dictionary has `m` items, the loop will only insert `m // 2` values from the dictionary into the list.  (Then you also add the last item, but you will still have missing items if `m > 3`).

To correctly convert a dictionary to a list of the required format (key then value, in sorted order) can be done as follows:

```
import itertools

# d is a dictionary
my_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(sorted(my_dict.items())))
```

To explain

```
my_list = list(
    # glue all of the sorted (key, value) pairs together
    itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        # sort the (key, value) pairs, giving a list [(k, v), ...]
        sorted(
            # get all of the (key, value) pairs in the dict
            my_dict.items())))
```

From your comment, that it is homework, and you cannot import anything ... then consider simply looping over sorted keys, adding key and value to a initially blank list ...

Comment: There isn't enough information in the OP to give an actual answer.

Comment: The error they're getting indicates the list is of odd length, which is definitely enough information to indicate they cannot be converting a dictionary to the list format they expect.  Hence *that* is probably the real issue, and this is a solution to that.

Comment: This is for a homework assignment, and our professor says that we can't import anything to help us